# Does AWS DocumentDB Support Joining 3+ Collections In a Single Query?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aws-documentdb

Is it possible to join 3 separate collections together in AWS DocumentDB with a single query (similar to the solution to the thread here: [How can I perform nested “joins” (joining 3 or more collections) in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66032673/14640164)

I feel like it may not, but I don't think AWS comes right out and specifically says so anywhere.

The [Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.lookup) says:

> Amazon DocumentDB supports the ability to do equality matches (for
> example, left outer join) but does not support uncorrelated
> subqueries.

That would be more helpful if I knew what an "uncorrelated subquery" was.

Also, the [list of MongoDB APIs that DocumentDB supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html#mongo-apis-aggregation-pipeline-variable) says that `$let` variable operator is outright not supported. Is the `$let` variable operator they're referring to exactly the same as the `let` expression within the `$lookup` stage that's used in the following query to join together 3 collections?

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "orders",
      let: { customer_id: "$customer_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$customer_id", "$customer_id"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "orderitems",
            localField: "order_id",
            foreignField: "order_id",
            as: "items"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "orders"
    }
  }
])
```

Is joining 3+ collections within a single NoSQL query possible in AWS DocumentDB, and if not, what would be the recommended / most efficient way to do this?

Comment: See (Join Conditions and Uncorrelated Sub-queries)[Join Conditions and Uncorrelated Sub-queries] introduced in MongoDB 3.6.   I believe DocumentDB has feature parity with MongoDB 3.4

Comment: If you meant to post a link, it's not working.

Comment: Yeah, messed that up. I was trying to link to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries

Comment: I still don't understand what an uncorrelated subquery is. That page doesn't really break down what that term means. Can you elaborate on what that term means?

Answer (score 2):

In [DocumentDB doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html):

> Amazon DocumentDB supports the ability to do equality matches (for example, left outer join) but does not support uncorrelated subqueries.

In [MongoDB doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/):

**equality match** has the following syntax:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

**uncorrelated subqueries** has the following syntax:

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       let: { <var_1>: <expression>, …, <var_n>: <expression> },
       pipeline: [ <pipeline to execute on the collection to join> ],
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

So the 2nd syntax is not supported in DocumentDB.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to execute pipeline on joined collection with documentDB? It's annoying the syntax isn't supported.